# powershell. Помогите реализовать поиск значений из списка, подсчёт количества повторений и вывести сумму

Tags: powershell

Имеем список кодов $call:

```
5001
1100
1131
1110
1120
1110
1100
1100
1110
1120
1131
5001
1100
1110
1131
1121
1110
1120
1131
1120
1120
1100
1120
1100
1120
1121
1100
1120
```

Требуется осуществить поиск в списке кодов по кодам указанным во втором списке. Например: нам нужно узнать сколько раз повторяются коды **1131** **1121** **1100** (их количество может быть разное) и вывести сумму всех повторений.

Пробовал делать так:

```
$str = "1121"
$Pattern = "\b(?:{0})\b" -f ($str -join '|')
$Count = ($call -split $Pattern).Count - 1
```

Но не удобно тем, что для каждый поиск каждого кода требуется отдельно писать код.

Answer (score 1):

```
-split @"
5001
1100
1131
1110
1120
1110
1100
1100
1110
1120
1131
5001
1100
1110
1131
1121
1110
1120
1131
1120
1120
1100
1120
1100
1120
1121
1100
1120
"@ | Group-Object -NoElement
```

```
PS C:\Users\alHaos> 
Count Name
----- ----
    7 1100
    5 1110
    8 1120
    2 1121
    4 1131
    2 5001
```